# Filter custom JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, filter, vuetify.js

I have this JSON

```
const Menu = [{
    icon: "home",
    text: "Inicio",
    url: {
        name: "home"
    },
    typeUrl: "exact"
},
{
    heading: "Operaciones"
},
{
    icon: "settings",
    "icon-alt": "settings",
    text: "Operación",
    model: true,
    children: [{
        icon: "add",
        text: "Cargar Pedidos",
        url: {
            name: "cargarpedidos"
        }
    },
    {
        icon: "playlist_add_check",
        text: "Aprobar Pedidos"
    },
    {
        icon: "content_copy",
        text: "Remitir Pedidos"
    }
    ]
},
{
    heading: "Informes"
},
{
    icon: "widgets",
    "icon-alt": "widgets",
    text: "Informe",
    model: false,
    children: [{
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Usuarios"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Permisos Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Resetear Password"
    },
    {
        icon: "view_module",
        text: "Cambiar Password"
    }
    ]
},
{
    heading: "APSI"
},
{
    icon: "view_module",
    text: "Informes del APSI"
},
{
    heading: "Administaciones"
},
{
    icon: "extension",
    "icon-alt": "extension",
    text: "Administración",
    model: false,
    children: [{
        icon: "face",
        text: "Usuarios"
    },
    {
        icon: "assignment_ind",
        text: "Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "settings",
        text: "Permisos Perfiles"
    },
    {
        icon: "cached",
        text: "Resetear Password"
    },
    {
        icon: "fingerprint",
        text: "Cambiar Password"
    }
    ]
},
{
    heading: "Mantenimientos"
},
{
    icon: "build",
    "icon-alt": "build",
    text: "Mantenimiento",
    model: true,
    children: [{
        icon: "group_work",
        text: "Departamentos"
    },
    {
        icon: "room",
        text: "Locales"
    },
    {
        icon: "donut_large",
        text: "Unidades de Medida"
    },
    {
        icon: "spellcheck",
        text: "Articulos"
    },
    {
        icon: "toc",
        text: "Categorías"
    },
    {
        icon: "supervisor_account",
        text: "Usuario Aprobador"
    }
    ]
}
];

export default Menu;
```

I use it to create the menu of my system that I am developing with VueJS + Vuetify and I need to filter it through the "text" field by words that contain it regardless of position, in the style of SQL's like '%filter%', also without distinguish upper and lower case. As far as possible don't distinguish accents (but this is already very picky, if it is not possible or it is very cumbersome, I can skip it).

Also in the case that the pattern of coincidence is in a child node and not in the father, does this father also have to appear in the filter, is it possible to do this with a Javascript function?

The menu looks like this:

[image]

I expect this behavior

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of the parameters you want to pass to the filter, and what the result would look like?

Comment: yes, I have added it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if you want to get  `text` fields of children, I think something like that should do it. You just need to initialize all your parents with empty children arrays:

```
 tempArr = Menu.filter(function (elem) {
  return elem.children == null ;
}); 
 textFields = tempArr.map(({ text }) => text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can filter match regular expression in an array.

```js
var arr = [{
    icon: "add",
    text: "Cargar Pedidos",
    url: {
      name: "cargarpedidos"
    }
  },
  {
    icon: "playlist_add_check",
    text: "Aprobar Pedidos"
  },
  {
    icon: "content_copy",
    text: "Remitir Pedidos"
  },
  {
    icon: "content_copy",
    text: "Remitir Pedisddos"
  },
  {
    icon: "content_copy",
    text: "Remitir Pediados"
  },
  {
    icon: "content_copy",
    text: "Remitir asdaasd"
  }
];

var name = "dido";
var regex = "/" + name + "/g";
var filtered = arr.filter(
  (val) => val.text.match(name)
);

console.log(filtered);
```

These are the basics of filtering. If you want to search for any property in an array object than use this function:

```
var result = Menu.filter(function(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).some(function(k) {
    return o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('dido') != -1;
  })
})

console.log(result)
```